# Algorithm to score aptitude test to yield highest possible correlations with outcome

Tags: psychometrics, scoring-rules

My problem concerns an aptitude test containing a set of single choice items ($x_1 x_2 .. x_n$). For each item, the participant may have selected option 1 to 5. These choices are scored dichotomously (1 = correct, 0 = incorrect) according to a predefined scorebook and the sum score for each participant is calculated.

However, I need to  re-score these choices, not by the scorebook but to maximize the correlation between the resulting sum score and another outcome variable ($y$). The goal is to finally determine if other "correct" values for each item can be identified, that will show stronger relationships with outcome variables.

I've been told that this method is referred to as **empirical scoring**, but so far I haven't found anything of relevance in literature yet.

Perhaps someone here knows what I am looking for, or ideally point me towards a R-library that incorporates an algorithm for this "empirical scoring" method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of such a practice, but it sounds like data-dredging. You're searching through a very large number of ways to code items so as to maximize a degree of association. If you want to do it anyway, you can brute-force it by simply calculating the correlation induced by every possible coding, which is doable if you have only a few items. If you have $n$ items, there are $5^n$ possible codings.

Comment: Thanks. That was my original thought as well. Unfortunately, my case concerns 72 items, so a brute force approach doesn't seem feasible.